# Feynman rules for exchange graphs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I'm looking into second-order Feynman diagrams in QED and something is unclear to me regarding the existence of both a direct and exchange graph. The way I understand it is that there are two ways in which momentum can be exchanged between the interacting particles, and both have to be accounted for. Is this correct? How is it generalized when going to higher orders?

Next, when the Feynman rules are listed, I've never seen one addressing the exchange graph, so how does one correctly predict it without going through the full calculation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be clear from Wick's theorem?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? In what way would Wick's theorem explain it?

Comment: Ah, never mind. Judging from your comments on Vadim's answer, I appear to have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feynmann diagrams (including the corresponding rules) are a method of carrying out calculations - every diagram is uniquely associated with a mathematical expression. The advantage is that drawing diagrams is often easier than doing the math... but, if you want to prove that the math behind is correct, there is no way of avoiding it.

In other words, your question of how to predict certain type of graphs without actually doing calculations does not make much sense. Though I do agree that the hand-wave explanations given to such graphs (often based on udnerstanding the math behind) may give the impression that one somehow comes up with Feynman rules purely by discussing their physical meaning.

Comment: Of course, the rules come after doing the math and I'm not trying to assign predictive power to the diagrams. What I meant is that knowing that the math gives two terms, an exchange one and a direct one, is there a rule connected with this, so that I can accurately represent a matrix element (which must contain both terms)?

Comment: If you write the matrix element directly, without diagrams/Wick's theorem/etc., the two terms literally come from the direct and exchange (Hartree and Fock) terms in basic QM. Perhaps, this point is hidden, if you are studying relativistic QFT, but in condensed matter QFT books these are often discussed in gory details - e.g.,  in Fetter&Walecka or even in Mattuck (which is not a very serious book, but very insightful).

Comment: Alright I see what you mean. So if the non-contracted operators are fermionic I should have a sort of Slater determinant of graphs? And if I had both fermionic and bosonic a Slater determinant for the former and permanent for the latter?

Comment: @KarimChahine Indeed, second quantization encodes particle indistingushability as the commutation properties of the operators - by construction. Whereas in the first quantization it is encoded in the wave function (Slater determinants for fermions or symmetrized wave functiosn for bosons). If you now review the second quantization procedure, you will see where it happens.